# How do I get a network drive File System object in Java

Tags: java, userprincipal

I'm want to use the getUserPrincipalLookupService in the FileSystem class, but can only seem to get my personal FileSystem through FileSystems.getDefault().

My goal is to set the owner of a file (on the network drive) as a specific user on the network drive.

Answer (score 0):

If your network drive is mapped to `H:`

```
FileSystems.getFilesystem(new File("H:\\").toURI())
```